# How do I free up space to install software updates?

Tags: upgrade

The upgrade needs a total of 87.5 M free space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 32.8 M of disk space on '/boot'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo apt-get autoclean`

Also FSlint is a utility which scans the entire FS (filesystem hence the name FSlint) for anything that can be removed *including whitespaces* (there might be a better one)

there is also remove orphaned packages tool which does you know what